# AWS: how to restrict access to API gateway from Amplify app?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, aws-amplify

I have an Amplify app which I'd like to be the only one allowed to call an API gateway.

What's the best way to achieve that?

It seems [possible to make the gateway private to a single VPC](https://gist.github.com/skorfmann/6941326b2dd75f52cb67e1853c5f8601) - but it seems like [AWS Amplify app can't be placed inside any single VPC](https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-hosting/issues/794).

Are there other ways? Can I whitelist based on arn? IP? Other options?

Comment: did you find a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, VPC support is currently not available out of the box (may be in the future).

Some workarounds I've used are:

- Whitelist the API gateway only to your IP address
- Integrate private API gateway + Cloudfront and place WAF in front of it

REF:
https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-hosting/issues/12